# Converting grayscale JPEG image to RGB leads to 9 channels

Tags: image, matlab, imread

Trying to convert some grayscale images to RGB (1,1,1).. I have a folder of about 1500 images that I need batch converted using the code below (which works well with individual images)

Interestingly enough,

```
imwrite(repmat(imread(files(1).name), [1 1 3]),files(1).name)
imwrite(repmat(imread(files(2).name), [1 1 3]),files(2).name)
imwrite(repmat(imread(files(3).name), [1 1 3]),files(3).name)
```

...(and so forth)

works just fine

```
files = dir('*.jpeg')
for I=1:length(files)
    imwrite(repmat(imread(files(i).name), [1 1 3]),files(i).name)
    display(i)
end
```

> Error using writejpg (line 46)
>   Data with 9 components not supported for JPEG files.
>
> Error in imwrite (line 485)
>           feval(fmt_s.write, data, map, filename, paramPairs{:});

Comment: You iterate "I" and use "i" in your loop.

Comment: You use capital I for loops. Try changing it to lowercase i.

Comment: `i` is for imaginary numbers in MATLAB. Please do not overshadow the builtin definition of `i` by using it as a variable name. Instead change `i` to upper-case `I`

Comment: It seems that you are trying to "rgb-ise" a file that you've already processed. I recommend to check size(img,3) after reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Use the correct variable name for looping, i.e. `i` or `I` but not a mix! Note that `i` has a built in definition as the imaginary constant, so you're better of using `I`, or something different entirely.
2. You show a warning for JPEGs with 9 elements not being supported when trying to write the file. This suggests you've blindly used `repmat` to triplicate an image which is already RBG.

We can address both of these like so:

```
files = dir('*.jpeg')
for k = 1:length(files)
    img = imread( files(k).name ); % Load the image first
    % Convert greyscale to RBG if not already RGB
    % If it's already RBG, we don't even need to overwrite the image        
    if size(img,3) == 1
        imwrite(repmat(img, [1 1 3]), files(k).name);
    end
    % Display progress
    display(k)
end
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks. Follow up question - if I have files in multiple sub folders, I get an error when using img = imread( files(k).name ) - as if it cannot read the subfolders' files :Error using imread>get_full_filename (line 516)
File "img_1.jpg" does not exist.

Comment: You can only use the file name (without a path) if the file is in the current directory. As soon as you want to use a different path, you need to specify it. This should work: `img = imread( fullfile( files(k).folder, files(k).name ) );`. Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.